# Запись и чтение Сектора диска С++

Tags: c++, windows, диск

Хочу записывать и читать информацию прямиком из сектора диска а не из файла. На С++. Приложите пример по максимуму простой. Или ссылку дайте. Посекторное чтение и запись я полагаю даст мне возможность делать полные посекторные копии нескольких ОС и разделов сразу. Также делать защиту программ от взлома.

вот финальный код ширения основан на ответе.Чтение первого сектора первого диска.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int win_error()
{
    cout<<"error"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{


 HANDLE hDisk = ::CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hDisk == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) throw win_error();

    BYTE buf[512];
    DWORD dwRead;
    if (!::ReadFile(hDisk, buf, sizeof(buf), &dwRead, NULL) || dwRead != sizeof(buf)) throw win_error();
    ::CloseHandle(hDisk);


    ofstream out("1.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i<512;i++)
    {
        char f[3];  itoa(buf[i],f,16);
        out<<i<<"\t"<<f<<"\t"<<buf[i]<<'\n';
        cout<<buf[i];
    }
    out.close();
    system("1.txt");
    //cin.get();
}
```

Визуалку надо от имени админа запускать, проект создавать не консольный а пустой enemy. Буду благодарен если кто то ещё покажет как [позицию чтение установить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/852737/readfile-%D0%A1-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). и записывать в заданную позицию, можно в 32 сектор писать для примера, там никогда ничего важного нет. Благодарен всем участникам.

Comment: Если это без ОС то читать int 13h, либо... низкоуровневая работа с портами контроллера + DMA + USB. Если используя windows - CreateFile/ReadFile. ОС может заблокировать запись/чтение диска, или подменить области. Если линукс юникс - как-то ещё.

Comment: Из под ОС вы не имеете права делать ввод вывод куда угодно, можно это делать с уровня драйвера. По драйверам - отдельный вопрос, и скорее всего врядли тут подскажут.

Comment: Вот ваш вопрос и ответ в англ-версии https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33666574/invalid-handle-value-when-using-createfile-c

Comment: Есть програмка DMDE Она позволяет из под виндовса переписывать сектора, без установи чего либо еще.

Comment: И внимательно читать MSDN https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea

Comment: Спасибо я попробую розобратся.

Comment: @nick_n_a, какой ещё `int 13h`? Мы в защищённом режиме, а начиная с `10h` там другие прерывания, задаваемые операционной системой. То есть BIOS-овское `int 13h` работать не будет.

Comment: @Arhad тогда не было уточнения о защищённом режиме и метки винда не было.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В принципе, если не хотеть странного вроде небуферизованного ввода/вывода, то там все так же, как и для файлов. Диски открываются все той же функцией CreateFile, но для dwShareMode надо обязательно указывать (FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE), а в dwCreationDisposition должно (естественно) стоять OPEN_EXISTING. В качестве имени должно стоять, например, для физического диска "\\.\PhysicalDrive0", а для логического - "\\.\C:". А дальше все так же, как и для файла - читаем ReadFile, пишем WriteFile, закрываем CloseHandle.

В описании CreateFile все это подробно расписано, и если вы действительно будете это делать, читать MSDN вам скорее всего все равно придется. Имейте только ввиду, что начиная с Висты доступ к диску требует поднятия привилегий (elevation). То есть программу нужно 1) запустить с учетки администратора, 2) в манифесте должно стоять требования административных привилегий, и 3) при каждом запуске юзер должен подтверждать, что да, он действительно хочет запустить эту опасную программу (которая у вас, вероятно, даже не подписана сертификатом). Без этого CreateFile будет просто возвращать ошибку ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

UPD: С утра набросал крохотную демонстрашку, она читает самый первый сектор диска С: (писать туда не стал, но тоже можно:). Исключение win_error только замените на какую-нибудь свою обработку.

```
    HANDLE hDisk = ::CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\C:", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hDisk == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) throw win_error();

    BYTE buf[512];
    DWORD dwRead;
    if (!::ReadFile(hDisk, buf, sizeof(buf), &dwRead, NULL) || dwRead != sizeof(buf)) throw win_error();
    ::CloseHandle(hDisk);
```

Как уже было сказано, запускать надо командой "Run as Administrator" иначе CreateFile вернет ошибку.

Comment: `(FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE)` — уверены? Раз требуются эти флаги, значит диск примонтирован, то есть находится в использовании операционной системой. **Прямая работа с томом, который уже кем-то открыт, крайне опасна** — первая же операция записи со стороны другого открывшего повредит файловую систему на нём, что приведёт к потере данных,  полной или частичной (в зависимости от места повреждения).

Comment: Сначала надо 1) отмонтировать диск вызовом `DeleteVolumeMountPointW()`, 2) попытаться открыть диск в эксклюзивном режиме (т. е. безо всяких `FILE_SHARE_*`), 3) при неудаче [получить список мешающих процессов](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36300877/2553424) + их главных окон и показать его пользователю с просьбой закрыть их для продолжения. Ну а по завершении не забыть примонтировать диск обратно [с помощью `SetVolumeMountPoint`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3788057/2553424). Разумеется, исходн*ые* точк*и* надо вначале [сохранить](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16889043/2553424).

Comment: Не хватает: размер считываемой информацию должен быть кратен размеру блока блочного устройства, т.е. 512, 1024 и т д. По одному байту читать нельзя.

Comment: @nick_n_a, да, верно. Забыл упомянуть, что читать нужно секторами (спать уже хотелось:).

Comment: @Arhad, да, в своем ответе я абсолютно уверен, он основан на достаточно большом личном опыте (и на чтении документации, неожиданно так). Про работу с диском в эксклюзивном доступе в исходном вопросе ничего не было. Диск С: тоже эксклюзивно читаете, кстати?

Comment: @Arhad, то, что вы написали, нужно делать для программы чтения/восстановления образов типа Акрониса, для обычной работы с диском ничего такого не нужно. "первая же операция записи со стороны другого открывшего повредит файловую систему на нём" - вот только глупостей не нужно, пожалуйста. Писать на диск можно, и ничего операция записи не повредит, если, разумеется, не писать куда попало.

Comment: @freim, `Писать на диск можно, и ничего операция записи не повредит...` — согласен, но это всё риски. Ладно, можно попросить пользователя закрыть программы, но службы (тот же Prefetcher) могут начать работу с файлом аккурат во время внесения нами изменений в NTFS-запись либо этого файла, либо какой-нибудь директории выше по иерархии. И ещё вопрос, как это наложится на то, что драйвер файловой системы закешировал внутри себя (он же не знает про работу в обход его).

Comment: И что будет после того, как этот самый драйвер решит сбросить на диск уже давно удерживаемый в памяти кэш записи, который с определённой вероятностью может наложиться поверх наших изменений?

Comment: @freim `и на чтении документации, неожиданно так` — а документация гарантирует, что изменения, внесённые в сектора с содержимым файлов сразу же будут доступны через тот же `CreateFile()`? (хорошо, опустим директории и маленькие файлы, содержимое которых помещается прямо внутрь сектора с NTFS-записью, а также добавление/удаление/перемещение секторов). Если нет, значит драйвер файловой системы не в курсе про вносимые нами изменения — придётся постоянно вызывать `FlushFileBuffers()`, откуда-то беря для него дескрипторы, и молиться, чтобы планировщик задач не запустил в это время дефрагментатор.

Comment: это все полбеды. Есть ещё две файловые системы FAT32 (для флешек чаще, и старых компов) и NTFS (их больше, но под виндой их чаще всего одна-две). Структура NTFS достаточно сложная, есть файлы хранящиеся в MFT напрямую, есть обычные файлы, если упакованые и шифрованые файлы... Можно ли охватить все тонкости... незнаю.

Comment: Писать в shared-режиме в области диска, соответствующие примонтированному тому с файловой системой - явный выстрел в ногу, не важно молиться или нет. К счастью, Windows, начиная с висты, просто не даст этого сделать. В неразмеченные области или загрузочный сектор, конечно, можно писать и так.

Comment: Напомню, что вопрос был просто о возможности прямого чтения/записи секторов диска. Зачем - нужно спрашивать у автора запроса (мне показалось, он сам толком не знает). Но предполагается, что человек, который в это дело лезет, сам понимает зачем ему это нужно, и осознает возможные сложности. Вы же почему-то сразу решили что диск непременно NTFS и автор хочет править MFT или что-то в этом роде. Из вопроса этого не следует.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, "К счастью, Windows, начиная с висты, просто не даст этого сделать" - даст. "В неразмеченные области или загрузочный сектор, конечно, можно писать и так" - нельзя. С поднятием привилегий писать можно в любое место. Без - никуда нельзя писать, и читать тоже. Просто CreateFile вернет ошибку.

Comment: @freim https://support.microsoft.com/en-ph/help/942448/changes-to-the-file-system-and-to-the-storage-stack-to-restrict-direct "*Без - никуда нельзя писать, и читать тоже.*" - Я знаю. Я не про права администратора, а про shared-режим.