# ReadFile С++ Позиция чтения

Tags: c++, windows

CreateFile
readfile

Я читаю сектора винчестера

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int win_error()
{
    cout<<"error"<<endl;
    return 0;
}

int main()
{


 HANDLE hDisk = ::CreateFile("\\\\.\\PhysicalDrive0", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hDisk == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) throw win_error();

    {
    BYTE buf[512];
    DWORD dwRead;

    for(int i = 0; i<33;i++)
    if (!::ReadFile(hDisk, buf, sizeof(buf), &dwRead, NULL) || dwRead != sizeof(buf)) throw win_error();


    {
    ofstream out("1.txt");
    for(int i = 0; i<512;i++)
    {
        char f[3];  itoa(buf[i],f,16);
        out<<i<<"\t"<<f<<"\t"<<buf[i]<<'\n';
        //cout<<buf[i];
    }
    out.close();
    system("1.txt");
    }








     ::CloseHandle(hDisk);
    //cin.get();
}

}
```

Но допустим мне не нужно читать все сектора последовательно а только 22 как пропустить (22 * sizeof(char)) и прочитать сразу 22 рой сектор. (программа работает только с админ правами)

[Вопрос связан с...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/852186/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%A1)

Comment: Точно так же как и для обычных файлов SetFilePointer или SetFilePointerEx https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfilepointer С оговоркой - (аналогично размеру) позиция кратно размеру блока (512 или 1024). Т.е грубо номер_сектора*512 нужно передать в ф-цию.

Comment: @nick_n_a, ответ исчерпывающий, тут больше ничего не добавить. Правильней бы это в ответ и перенести.